# Probability that a DNA sequence of length 4 consists of four different letters.

Tags: probability

Given: Probabilities of getting a base is given by $P(A)=p_A$, $P(C)=p_C$, $P(T)=p_T$, and $P(G)=p_G$.

Find the probability that a DNA sequence of length 4 consists of four different letters with no repeated letters among those four letters.

My attempt: $\dfrac{4!}{4^4} = \dfrac{3}{32}$. I don't think I did it correctly since I didn't use any of the given information. Can someone clarify this?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that the probability of each letter is NOT just $\frac{1}{4}$. The probability of the sequence $ACTG$ (in that order) is $p_Ap_Cp_Tp_G$. Can you compute the probability of the other $4!-1$ sequences that use $A,C,T,G$ exactly one time each? Then, add all of these together to get the probability of using $A,C,T,G$ each exactly once, but in any order.

Comment: Thank you Jimmy. The problem assumes independence so each sequence will have the probability of $p_A p_C p_T p_G$. Now there are $4!$ of them so the answer would be $4!p_A p_C p_G p_T$. Let me know if you have any suggestions.